# Divide training and testing for caffe to reduce memory usage

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am training my network and as it seems there is enough memory for testing the net but not enough memory for the training:

```
I0411 16:41:04.669823  6823 solver.cpp:331] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0411 16:43:31.625444  6823 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #0: intermediate_loss = nan (* 1 = nan loss)
I0411 16:43:31.625897  6823 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #1: loss = nan (* 1 = nan loss)
F0411 16:43:33.259964  6823 syncedmem.cpp:71] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x2ae6f6039b2d  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x2ae6f603b995  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x2ae6f60396a9  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x2ae6f603c42e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x2ae6f4e7b0c8  caffe::SyncedMemory::mutable_gpu_data()
    @     0x2ae6f4ce8143  caffe::Blob<>::mutable_gpu_diff()
    @     0x2ae6f4ec3bc6  caffe::EltwiseLayer<>::Backward_gpu()
    @     0x2ae6f4e38dab  caffe::Net<>::BackwardFromTo()
    @     0x2ae6f4e38def  caffe::Net<>::Backward()
    @     0x2ae6f4e5d763  caffe::Solver<>::Step()
    @     0x2ae6f4e5e2da  caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
    @     0x2ae6f4e516c4  caffe::NCCL<>::Run()
    @           0x40ebda  train()
    @           0x40b983  main
    @     0x2ae70b5fab35  __libc_start_main
    @           0x40c42d  (unknown)
```

In my `solver.prototxt` I have `test_net: ...` and `train_net: ...`. I have the feeling that caffe uses more memory when testing and training. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you have different batch sizes for training and testing? You can prevent this error by just reducing the training batch size.

Comment: Well, reducing the training batch size might lead to less good results. Why is the memory usage of training higher than testing? @ParagS.Chandakkar

Comment: Because in training, you have compute gradients while back-propagating... that will take up a lot of space. It is true that reducing training batch size will lead to performance reduction sometimes, but a decent batch size like 32 or 50 should okay.